# JavaScript nested object array, How to loop through the 'KEY' of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
var myCollection = {
"cars": [
          { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
          { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
          { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
        ]
}
for ( x in myCollection ) {
  document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML += x + "<br />";
}
```

**Ans : cars** 
Likewise how can I display the **'KEY'** value which is inside the array *i.e.*  **'name'** or **'models'**

```
for ( x in myCollection.cars ) {
  document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML += x + "<br />"; 
}
```

**Ans : 
 0 
 1 
 2** 
Why it returns array index value, How can I display the 'KEY' value **'name'** or **'models'** ?

**Expected Ans:**

```
name      models 

name  OR  models 

name      models
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for loops are looping through each index, so you then have to take that index and drill into the array

```
var myCollection = {
"cars": [
          { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
          { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
          { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
        ]
}
for ( x in myCollection.cars ) {
  var keys = Object.keys(myCollection.cars[x])
  document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML += keys[0] + "<br />";
}
```

the myCollection.cars[x] is how you get the specific object in the array and from the Object.keys() gives you the keys of that object. If you want the value and the key

```
for ( x in myCollection.cars ) {
  var keys = Object.keys(myCollection.cars[x])
  document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML += 
     keys[0] + " : " + myCollection.cars[x].name + " <br />" +
     keys[1] + " : " + myCollection.cars[x].models + "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: myCollection.cars[keys[0]] returns undefined but keys[0] and keys[1] works fine as I expected.

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko changed it to var so you wouldnt have that issue

Answer (score 0):

This `for in` is mean't for object's. You are using an array so its returning index. Instead use a forEach like shown below.

```js
var myCollection = {
    "cars": [
              { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
              { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
              { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
            ]
    }
    myCollection.cars.forEach(function (value) {
      //console.log("name" + value.name + ", models" + value.models);
      //for printing cars alonecars
      console.log(value.name);
      //for print models alone
      value.models.forEach(function (model) {
        console.log(model);
      });
    });
```

The line below comments will get your desired output, you can print either cars or models.

Comment: I know how to display a string value, I want to know how to LOOP through the 'KEY' or 'NAME' value of the nested array. Please revise the Expected Answers in my Question.

Comment: @JeevaRaam Updated my answer can you please check?

Comment: 'for in' loop is more dynamic to loop through the 'value' values and I know how to do it, but what I was expecting is to loop the 'name' values.

Comment: @JeevaRaam Glad you found the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/sg6kj0n7/1/

```js
var myCollection = {
"cars": [
          { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
          { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
          { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
        ]
}
for ( var x in myCollection.cars ) {
 for (var key in myCollection.cars[x]) {
    document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML += key + "   ";
  }
  document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML += "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id ="id1">

</div>
```

Comment: I know how to loop through the 'VALUE' value, I want to know how to loop through the 'KEY' or 'NAME' value of the nested array.

Comment: @JeevaRaam . I have updated the answer. Solution will work irrespective  of **N** number of keys.